# Direct Message to more than one person : twitter MGTwitterEngine

Tags: ios4, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I want to send direct message to more than one person with a single call

I am using MGTwitterEngine

and calling function like this

```
[requestDict setObject:@"direct_message" forKey:[twitterObj sendDirectMessage:@"this is test from iphone app" to:@"user_id"]];
```

this is sending ok

but am not able to send it to multiple people , how can I do this
I tried it with comma separated user_ids but not works

Thanks
Amit Battan

Comment: How to send message to single follower ? I am unable to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether MGTwitterEngine supports a call that looks like it allows you to send a direct message (DM) to more than one user, the Twitter API doesn't support a call like that.

The API method behind the scenes ([direct_messages/new](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/direct_messages/new)) only allows the authenticating user to send a DM to one user only.  So, if the single call is working for you, just iterate over your list of Twitter users and send them the DM with the call you specified.

Also, you don't have to worry about rate limiting when sending a DM.